# PHP+MySQL:- Get title from parent ID row

Tags: php, mysql

Hello this is my first question here. I am new to php mysql and hope will get some help from you all expert.

I am having a table for blog and trying to get title if type="C" has audio file. Please refer image for table details

Here is the image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK9Cr.jpg

I can write some simple query but this is quite complex for me to understand how can I get title while checking if `C` has audio file and not null

Query:
`"SELECT * FROM blogpost WHERE type='P' AND audio IS NOT NULL";`

This is obvious not going to render anything and this is my confusion how can I write query where it will determine `C` in this way `"SELECT * FROM blogpost WHERE type='C' AND audio IS NOT NULL";` but than here how can I get title of `P`?

Can anyone help me to get the title for `P` type.

Comment: Please include all of your code (working or not) in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join on `blogpost` again so you have a table for the parent and for the child.

```
SELECT p.title FROM blogpost p
JOIN blogpost c ON (p.postid = c.Parentid)
WHERE c.blogtype = 'C' AND c.audio IS NOT NULL
AND p.blogtype = 'P'
```

The last line is probably not necessary; only if `C` can be parents of `C` and you want to exclude those.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. This works but giving title for more than one time

Comment: @Artist what do you mean by more than one *time*?

Comment: Okay I can group it by c.parentid right? it works thanks a lot

Comment: I am unable to up vote as I am new. But I have selected the answer